# setup squid https proxy failed on windows server 2016

Tags: windows, https, proxy, server, squid

i want to setup a proxy server through https (for chinese to visit google etc), but cannot succeed, i use squid with the following config:

```
acl all src all
acl SSL_ports port 1-65535
acl Safe_ports port 1-65535
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all

https_port 443 cert=/etc/ssl/zaahan.cer key=/etc/ssl/zaahan.key cafile=/etc/ssl/zaahanca.crt

coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222

max_filedescriptors 3200
```

I think maybe there is something wrong with the config file, anyone can help me debug the config file of squid? 
thanks

Comment: What is logged in `/var/log/squid/access.log` for such requests ?

Comment: i finally find that my config file has no problem, it's because the 443 port has already be listened by other process(system), so what i fix it is to change the 443 port to another free port, like 4432, and then it works fine. thanks.

Comment: Thats good - you should write it up as your own answer below. I'm guessing it was IIS which was using the port already. There should have been some sort of warning in the squid logs when it started (or maybe the Windows logs)